# How to turn off a username and password prompt on an ASP web site hosted in IIS 6

Tags: web-server, iis-6, asp.net, web-hosting

Software developer here with very little networking experience looking for info on settings in IIS for hosting ASP.NET web apps...

We're self-hosting a website via an onsite web server (running Windows Server 2003) with IIS 6.0.  Anytime someone navigates to our site both externally & internally to the network, a prompt opens asking for a username & password...I've tested in multiple browsers and it does the same in all browsers.  I want to turn this off, but don't know how to.  We've tried disabling Windows Authentication inside of IIS, but this results in a "You are not authorized to view this page" error.

Any ideas on how I can get around this issue, both internally and externally?

Comment: Do you have Anonymous access enabled? It doesn't sound like it.

Comment: yes...Anonymous access is enabled, and Windows Authentication is disabled

Answer (score 1):

Do the IUSR* account have read access to the actual file-system? Does it work with a static html file/directory listing or anything that doesn't need to execute scripts/asp?

Maybe [this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;896861) applies to your problem?